# SELinux + MergerFS (fuse) not working well together

Tags: centos, permissions, selinux, fuse, proxmox

I have been trying now for several days to get my new server up and running. I am running CentOS with MergerFS to pool my drives and samba to host to my windows machines. All of this running in Proxmox as well.

Over the weekend I got a couple of hard drives to start my server out with and am unable to get the shares to work correctly with samba. I have narrowed down the issue and it is being caused by labels. SELinux requires my mergerfs pool to have a label of samba_share_t but for some reason, mergerfs is not letting me change it from fusefs_t. All of my drives are ext4, I am seeing a lot of posts online that say this can be caused by using ntfs but that can't be my issue.

Things I have tried:

- I have attempted to modify the fstab to include an option to set the
  context to samba_share_t, but when I do that I get an error say that
  fuse (used by mergerfs) init does not support the option "content".
- I have tried manually changing the label of the pool with chcon and I
  get an error that the operation is not supported.
- I have tried adding the pool folder with semange and then manually running
  restorecon and it still doesn't make a change to that specific folder.

Windows being able to see the folder but not able to access it is such a tease, so close yet so far away. If possible, I would like to not have to disable SELinux.

Comment: I don't think you can put SELinux labels on a FUSE filesystem. People using NTFS under Linux would have the same problem since the NTFS driver uses FUSE.

Comment: Found that out with tons of google digging, and wanted to confirm you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue with just a simple setting change

```
setsebool -P samba_share_fusefs=1
```

and then restarting the smb service.

Comment: Thank you! I would probably just have disabled SELinux, your solution is better.